# Adobe CQ/AEM - connect to DB from custom login module

Tags: java, aem

I've got a working custom login module that extends `org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.authentication.AbstractLoginModule`. It checks credentials against an LDAP source, and now I'd like to go out to a Database to get some additional data to write to the profile. I'd like to use the JDBC Connections Pool service, but I can't figure out how to get a reference to it.

My first guess was that there might be a way to get the `Session` object passed in the `doInit()` method to provide a service, but I can't find a way.

The `Session` itself seems to be set by the `CallbackHandler`. Is there some way to get a service reference by writing a `Callback`?

EDIT:
Based on helpful comments, I've also tried the following

```
BundleContext context = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(JdbcPoolService.class).getBundleContext();
//ServiceReference[] serviceRefs = context.getServiceReferences(JdbcPoolService.class.getName(), String.format("(%s=%s)", Constants.OBJECTCLASS, JdbcPoolService.class.getName()));
ServiceReference serviceRefs = context.getServiceReference(JdbcPoolService.class.getName());
```

The `FrameworkUtil` does give me access to the correct bundle. (I can see the bundle ID in a debugger and it does match with JDBC pool provider.) But I can't access the service. All requests for the reference come back null. I've tried getting a single reference, but because the JDBC pool is a service factory, I also tried (commented out code) getting the array - with the class name and a filter as parameters, or null and a filter as parameters to `getServiceReferences`.
If I was using the `@Reference` annotation, I'd include the target parameter. I'm guessing that this is what I'm missing. Maybe the filter to `getServiceReferences` is wrong?

Comment: Is this a standalone database separate from CQ?

Comment: yes - standalone db2, used for reads by multiple applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link provides information on connecting to SQL databases: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/jdbc.html .
In essence it shows how to deploy a bundle wrapping the HSQLDB driver in an OSGi bundle. Here is the POM they use:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">


<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.adobe.example.myapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>hsqldb-jdbc-driver-bundle</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>wrapper-bundle-hsqldb-driver</name>
  <url>www.adobe.com</url>
  <description>Exports the HSQL JDBC driver</description>
  <packaging>bundle</packaging>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId> 
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3</version> 
        <extensions>true</extensions> 
        <configuration> 
         <instructions> 
            <Embed-Dependency>*</Embed-Dependency>
            <_exportcontents>org.hsqldb.*</_exportcontents>
          </instructions>
        </configuration> 
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
      <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.9</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

And then you may get the `DataSourcePool` service to obtain a `javax.sql.DataSource` object. The article shows how to get it in JSP:

```
<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%><%
%><%@page session="false"%><%
%><%@ page import="com.day.commons.datasource.poolservice.DataSourcePool" %><%
%><%@ page import="javax.sql.DataSource" %><%
%><%@ page import="java.sql.Connection" %><%
%><%@ page import="java.sql.SQLException" %><%
%><%@ page import="java.sql.Statement" %><%
%><%@ page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%><%
%><html>
<cq:include script="head.jsp"/>
<body>
<%DataSourcePool dspService = sling.getService(DataSourcePool.class);
  try {
     DataSource ds = (DataSource) dspService.getDataSource("hsqldbds");   
     if(ds != null) {
         %><p>Obtained the datasource!</p><%
         %><%final Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
          final Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
          final ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_USERS"); 
          int r=0;
          while(resultSet.next()){
             r=r+1;
          } 
          resultSet.close();
          %><p>Number of results: <%=r%></p><%
      } 
   }catch (Exception e) {
        %><p>error! <%=e.getMessage()%></p><%
    } 
%></body>
</html>
```

In a servlet or service you can get a reference to `DataSourcePool` service using `@Reference` annotation:

```
@Reference
private DataSourcePool pool;
```

EDIT: you can try getting the service outside of a component using [FrameworkUtil class](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/FrameworkUtil.html)

```
BundleContext context = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(serviceClass).getBundleContext();
ServiceReference serviceRef = context.getServiceReference(serviceClass.getName());
Object service = context.getService(serviceRef);
```

EDIT (by jwepurchase): for the JDBC service, you need to get the service by its persistent ID

```
ServiceReference[] serviceRefs = context.getServiceReferences(null, String.format("(%s=%s)", Constants.SERVICE_PID, "com.day.commons.datasource.jdbcpool.JdbcPoolService.[your-id-here]"));
JdbcPoolService pool = (JdbcPoolService) context.getService(serviceRefs[0]);
```

Note that the first parameter to `getServiceReferences` is null. Passing the class name as the first parameter doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Unfortunately none of these scenarios apply in my situation. Login Modules don't have access to the same things as JSPs and components, so neither the JSP's "sling.getService(...)" nor the Servlet (or any other component) @Reference will work.

Comment: I'm guessing that I'll have to do this in an authentication handler, which is a component, and then @Reference will work.

Comment: Check EDIT, hope it helps.

Comment: Closer - see my question edit. Thanks for the help - I think I'm almost there!

Comment: Got it! I added just a bit to your answer to complete it for my specific case. Thanks again.

Comment: one point here is to ensure you have a finally block that will ensure all connections/resultsets etc are closed. We did something similar and because we did not do this ended up with performance issues!